# How to collect Updated Records In Spotfire

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst, spotfire-webplayer

"In Spotfire, what fields are updating every day, and how can I collect only the information for those updated records?" as

Example:

(Latest Data = Present Data-Previous Data)

(Need day to day  Automate Data Updates and Export in Spotfire )